# how to include other dll in php extension?

Tags: php, apache, php-extension

I want to customize a php extension (`php_ext.dll`) on Windows, but this extension need to use other `a.dll` file (this dll was build by myself).
PHP build ENV: vs2008 + win7
when I build `php_ext.dll`, I have add `a.lib` into php extension's project.

After build successful, I copy `a.dll` and `php_ext.dll` to php extension dir, then add `extension =php_ext.dll` into `php.ini`.

While I run `php -m` in Windows command, I can see this extension, but when i start Apache, this extension can not been load. Following is Apache error log:

> [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>   httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.64.74.148 for ServerName
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\php\php_ext.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because with `php -m` you run php binary, with apache you load php as dll.

In this case dll search order kicks in: in first case, a.dll is found because it's located where php binary is, but it's not found when apache binary is run, as it's not located in its directory, and also no other searched directory.

You can either copy a.dll do apache folder, or to any other searched one, eg c:\Windows.

Comment: That would be copy you additional `.dll.` to the `apache/bin` folder right!